# Authenticate a mobile handset using PHP

Tags: php, mobile

I am looking for a way to authenticate a mobile device for a web-app, ideally using PHP.

I currently authenticate PC users by their IP address as well as username/password to provide an extra level of security. We want to launch our application on mobile devices but would like a second layer of security beyond just username/password.

Obviously IP lookup is not applicable as the mobile devices may change their IP frequently.

I don't believe it is possible to lookup the Device ID number remotely to check its ID.

There are only a few mobile users and I have physical access to their devices.

Any ideas on the best way to do this?

Comment: fyi some PC users ip's change frequently too

Comment: or many are the same if they are all behind a proxy / gateway / firewall ...

Comment: Lawrence - thanks I know but all my users sit in 2 central offices with 2 fixed IPs

Answer (score 0):

Install a client SSL cert on each, and use that for authentication.

Answer (score 0):

What type of mobile device? Smartphone? IF so they may send the MSISDN with the HTTP headers. Sometimes but not always.

Comment: They will be all iPhone 3/4s plus possibly one Android device